# Can someone tell me where I went wrong

Tags: c

Can someone help me out with correcting this. The question was supposed to be (Write a code to get the value for expression 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ...... + x^n)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int power = 1,sum = 0,n,x , i;
    printf("Enter the number : ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Enter the limit to fill the following series : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        sum = sum + power; 
        while (i>0)
        {
            power = power * x;
            i = i - 1;
        }
        
    }
    printf("The sum is %d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile your C code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program. Don't forget to read on [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) the documentation of *every function* that you have not defined (e.g. `printf`, `scanf` etc). Be aware that [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) can fail. Your program should handle such failures.

Comment: Take inspiration from existing open source software like [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). **StackOverflow is not a do-my-homework website**

Comment: Someone can tell you, but you have to help yourself first. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Don't declare several variables on the same line, like you have done here.  Use one line per variable declaration instead.

Comment: The crux of your problem: your index variable is being incremented in the `for` loop, but decremented in the `while` loop.  If you really think you need two loops (I don't think you do), use *two separate index variables.*

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
while (i>0)
        {
            power = power * x;
            i = i - 1;
        }
```

to

```
   power = power * x;
```

As this loop is not required